# Angular + rails : How to define different route for two angular application created inside a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am using angular1.x and rails 5.0.1. I am newbie to angular. I have created two client(angular) applications. One for simple user and other for admin user. How can i define the different routes for admin and client such that when admin try to access  then `admin/index.routes.js` should be called. What is happing now it always calls `client/index.routes.js`. Can anyone please help me, how can i define different routes.

Remember: I have two `index.routes.js` files one for admin and other for client.

Comment: If you have two separate angular apps, you will always have separate routes defined for them.

Comment: @31piy thanks for your reply. I am using these different apps inside a rails application. You are right i got the different routes when i am using `gulp build` on both applications i got localhost:3000 for client and for admin localhost:3001 but the problem is after integrating these applications with rails. I can run `gulp build` only once. So thats where i am confused that how and for which application `gulp build` would be called